# htaccess URL rewrite issue - permalinks

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

I am having some issues trying to prettify some URL's. Basically I need to make this URL http://domain.com/actualfolder/fakepath/this-is-the-article.php to display content from this page http://domain.com/actualfolder/articlemanager.php.

The articlemanager.php is setup to receive a GET url variable in the way of the "this-is-the-article" and search for it in the database. If found, it will display content specific to that result. This part works.

The part that i can't make it to work is the htaccess rule.

This is my rule but it returns 404 not found or 500 if i don't use the initial slashes.

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fakepath/([^/.]+).php$ articlemanager.php?permalink=$1 [L]`

I could really use some help, so any suggestion is welcome.

EDIT: the htaccess file lies in the domain.com/actualfolder/ location

Comment: where is this htaccess file?

Comment: Is your .htaccess in root or in some sub directory?

Comment: the htaccess file lies in the domain.com/actualfolder/ location